# How to put Divider in Relative Layout Android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

this is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried to put this partial code at the end of my Relativelayout but it dosent show the divider

this is my divider code :

```
<View
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_name"
   />
```

so how can i show this divider below of my text view ?

Comment: where you have to put Divider??

Comment: end of the relative layout after the text view , show the divider bottom of the text view

Comment: why are you using relative layout LinearLayout use horizontal as well as vertical orintation

Comment: here you can use for space margin left right top bottam etc this can easily manage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_name" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your divider by

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your divider by

```
<View
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_name"
        android:background="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `TextView` height.

Change this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

I guess you textview cover up your divider. If you use `layout_weight="1"`, the textview fill the 'free' space of your layout, while `match_parent` fill the parent view.

More details about MATCH_PARENT here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT

Comment: layout_weight can't be used inside relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Test"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"     />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_name"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just changed RelativeLayout and TextView layout_height to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

The issue posted in question would have been resolved since its been a while,
for future reference linear layout allows us to show divider at different positions as specified eg:,-// case when divider in between items.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:showDividers="middle" 
    android:divider="?android:listDivider"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

while in case of relative layout we need to use View as specified in other answers, like.

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:listDivider"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```